# Installing Bootstrap Lightbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, installation, lightbox

Although I might get bashed for asking this, I'm still pretty new to Rails/Bootstrap and I was wondering how I can install **[this](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/)** Lightbox plugin for Bootstrap. I read the documentation and install instructions but they're quite vague (IMO) for beginners. Any advice or pointers will do!

These are the instructions:
[image]
"*Grab the latest CSS/JS files*" and place them where? Can't I just link them to my project in `application.js` with `//= require X`? Or a gem I can install?

"*Place this near on your page, probably near the end of the body section*" near my code? Shouldn't I place this JS code in `application.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick read and this is my understanding

**Note!: This version is for Bootstrap 4, for Bootstrap 3 use the older version**

 Download bootstrap 4 / 3 and add to your project and the bootstrap CSS and js   links to the page like you would do on a normal page.

**Grab the latest CSS / JS files from the CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ekko-lightbox.**

 Copy the CDN link for the ekko-lightbox and to the head section just below the CSS link on your page

**Place this near on your page, probably near the end of the body section:**

You need to add jquery code near the end of the boy section - Note: you need to download latest version of jquery and add the jquery link, like you would do to normal page in project

**Then simply add data-toggle to your anchor tags.**

For all the anchor tags in the page - you need ot add this attribute 'data-toggle' and so...

Hope this helps and given you some idea on how to follow the instructions